# Can't get POST parameters

Tags: python, http, post, parameters, webapp2

I'm developing a web app in Python using WebApp2 as framework.
I can't get the http POST request parameters submitted by filling a form.

That's the HTML code of the form I created

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Normal Login Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/loginN/" enctype="text/plain" >
eMail: <input type="text" name="eMail"><br/>
password: <input type="text" name="pwd"><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

That's the result of the POST request after pressing the submit button

```
POST /loginN/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: text/plain
Content_Length: 33
Content_Type: text/plain
Cookie: 
session=############
Host: ###########
Origin: ###########
Referer: ############
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
X-Appengine-City: #######
X-Appengine-Citylatlong: ########
X-Appengine-Country: ##
X-Appengine-Region: ##
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: ##

eMail=mymail@email.com
pwd=mypwd
```

That's the code of the POST request handler

```
class loginN(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        w = self.response.write
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        logging.info(self.request)
        logging.info(self.request.POST.get('eMail'))
        logging.info(self.request.POST.get('pwd'))
        email = self.request.POST.get('eMail')
        pwd = self.request.POST.get('pwd')
        w('<html>')
        w('<head>')
        w('<title>Data Page </title>')
        w('</head>')
        w('<p>Welcome! Your mail is: %s</p>' % email)
        w('<p>Your pwd is: %s</p>' % pwd)
        w('</body>')
```

BaseHandler is webapp2.RequestHandler extended for handling sessions (i tried with webapp2.RequestHandler also and i got the same results).

What I get every time is None for both parameters.

Any suggestions about how to solve the problem? I tried self.request.get also, instead self.request.POST.get, but it didn't work too (i didn't get None neither)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `enctype="text/plain"` attribute from the form, and then use `self.request.POST.get('eMail')` and `self.request.POST.get('pwd')`.

Edit: The reason why removing `enctype="text/plain"` works is because you want the enctype to be `"text/html"` (which is the default) in order for webapp2 to read the form as an html form. When it is just set to `"text/plain"`, the form's output is contained in the body of the request as just text, which is what you saw when you printed out the request. If you use `"text/plain"`, then you could access the form's output as a string by using:

```
form_string = str(self.request.body)
```

and then you could parse that string to get the key-value pairs. As you're already aware though, it is easier just to set the enctype to html to get the standard http-form functionality.

I couldn't specifically find `enctype` information in the documentation, but if you have other questions about the request object I suggest reading the [Webob Documentation](http://docs.webob.org/en/stable/api/request.html#) for a request object. Webapp2 uses Webob requests, so that documentation is the place to go to understand your request obejct.

Comment: It works without enctype="text/plain" 
Thank you! Could you explain me why?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Very kind! Thank you